# What does the calculateDataExtension function in the Workfront API do?

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Does this re-calculate custom form fields? I'm interested in this for re-calc of custom forms attached to tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what it does. It forces a recalculation of the custom expressions in the forms. This is sometimes necessary when you use cross object formulas and you update the remote record which does not update the local one automatically. You can do this for a single record or in bulk.